# ¿Cómo evito que se mueva el fondo al hacer clic en login?

Tags: html, css3

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Seccion para ModaLogin -->
 <div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="login"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog" >
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h2 class="text-center" class="modal-title">Iniciar sesion </h2>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="text-center social-btn">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><b>Facebook</b></a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><b>Twitter</b></a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-google"></i><b>Google</b></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <!-- Fin Seccion para ModaLogin -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.modal-open { overflow: hidden; }

.modal { display: none; overflow: hidden; position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1050; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; outline: 0;

} .modal.fade .modal-dialog { -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%); -ms-transform: translate(0, -25%); -o-transform: translate(0, -25%); transform: translate(0, -25%); -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out; -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out; -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out; transition: transform 0.3s ease-out; } .modal.in .modal-dialog { -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0); -ms-transform: translate(0, 0); -o-transform: translate(0, 0); transform: translate(0, 0); }

.modal-open .modal { overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; }

.modal-dialog { position: relative; width: auto; margin: 10px; }

.modal-content { position: relative; background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #999; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border-radius: 6px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); background-clip: padding-box; outline: 0; }

.modal-backdrop { position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1040; background-color: #000; } .modal-backdrop.fade { opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); } .modal-backdrop.in { opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50); }

.modal-header { padding: 15px; border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; min-height: 16.42857px; }

.modal-header .close { margin-top: -2px; }

.modal-title { margin: 0; line-height: 1.42857; }

.modal-body { position: relative; padding: 15px; }
```

Coloqué ese botón de login y cuando apliqué el estilo modal para que salga con registro para redes sociales, al hacer clic se mueve más y más al lado izquierdo.

[image: **Coloqué ese botón de login y cuando apliqué el estilo modal para que salga con registro para redes sociales, al hacer clic se mueve más y más al lado izquierdo.**]

Comment: Deberías mostrar el css del supuesto modal o lo que sea que abra el botón.

Comment: Hola amigo, debes de colocar tu codigo para asi poder probar y editarlo, es casi imposible adivinar lo que genera tu problema. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Pon el Max-width en 100% y si el modal se abre al lado izquierdo por eso la pagina se crece el width, si el modal abre en el centro entonces si la position no la tienes en fixed ponla a fixed.
Si el problema es solo el background ponle las dimensiones en width 100% al background-image.
Si compartieras tu código podriamos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

```
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal  {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: 0;

}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  outline: 0;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000;
}
.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  min-height: 16.42857px;
}

.modal-header .close {
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.modal-title {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.42857;
}

.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
}
```